# Widget Wont Update / Redraw

Tags: java, android-studio, android-widget

I have a widget that loaded image from SQLite. It updated whenever I add or delete item but the image is not updated. I already try to send a broadcast to AppWidgetProvider class but it didn't work too.

> class that extend AppWidgetProvider

```
private static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.fav_movie_widget);
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stack_view, intent);
    views.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);

    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, FavMovieWidget.class);
    toastIntent.setAction(FavMovieWidget.TOAST_ACTION);
    toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    Log.e(TAG, "onUpdate2: start" );
}

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onUpdate: start" );
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
```

> activity for update

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, FavMovieWidget.class);
int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.stack_view);
```

> what i already try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FavMovieWidget.class);       
intent.setAction(appWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), FavMovieWidget.class));
intent.putExtra(appWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

> the widget image not update
>   [preview widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGLIa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by adding this on updateAppWidget. 
this will triger onGetViewFactory on my service.

```
Random random = new Random();
intent.setType(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(1000)));
```

and use sendbroadcast in my activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FavMovieWidget.class);       
intent.setAction(appWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), FavMovieWidget.class));
intent.putExtra(appWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```